# User defined Jacobian in MATLAB's lsqnonlin

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

When using MATLAB's [lsqnonlin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) function, I am trying to give a user-defined Jacobian matrix, as described in the documentation.

The output of the objective function used in lsqnonlin should be a vector of unsquared values, which, when squared and summed, give the energy. However, should the Jacobian be the partial derivates of the *squared* or *unsquared* values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unsquared values is correct.